# Texture paint dog for Skyrim

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting

I am a complete newb at this and am trying to change the coloring on this dog (with permission from the original creator) to match mine and mod it into Skyrim, but when I try to paint it in texture paint I get the bit below.

It doesn't happen if I use Gimp to edit the image and then add it back on, but then I can't exactly see what part I am coloring.

How to go about this, preferably while keeping the furlike texture?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Blender, you can use a texture for the brush and stencil it on the model. Either create a sample fur texture in Gimp or use a picture, then stencil it in Blender. Here is example => textured apples: https://youtu.be/lmbAs9jE1vI?feature=shared